# How can I avoid getting out of space in LXD operations?

Tags: snap, lxd

I installed LXD 4.10 in an Ununtu 18.04 machine using the snap:

```bash
sudo install lxd
```

LXD is installed in `/var/span/lxd`. Since a small disk is mounted in `/var`, I get out of no free space for some operations. Creating storage pools out of `/var` does not solve the problem because I still have problems with commands as `lxc export` or `lxc publish`. These commands create files in the directories:

```
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/backups/instances
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/images
```

When images and backups are too big, the `/var` disk gets out of space.

What is the best practice to avoid getting out of space? My restriction is that I cannot mount another disk in `/var`.